# Is there a way to obtain documents from manual references using Spring WebFlux and MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm attempting to create a Spring-Data MongoDB repository using Spring WebFlux for use in my server backend.  I'm still very new to Spring-Data overall, and I'm trying to figure out how return a document from a manual reference using only a single GET request to my server.

For instance, lets say that I have the following document structure for my `Person` documents:

```
{
  "_id": "123",
  "person": "Test Person",
  "address": {
    "refId": "456",
    "name": "House"
  },
  "occupation": "Test occupation"
}
```

and the following structure for my `Address` documents:

```
{
  "_id": "456",
  "street": "Test Street",
  "houseNumber": "404"
}
```

I create a `PersonRepository` and `AddressRepository`, extending `ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String>` and `ReactiveMongoRepository<Address, String>` respectively.  This is great for when I want to query for individual `Person`(s) and `Address`(es), I've tested and it seems to work as expected.  My frontend is able to make GET requests to this backend (of the form /person/{id} and /address/{id}) and retrieve the correct data. However, whenever I want to obtain the `Address` for a specific `Person` I need to make two GET requests, one to get the `Person`, from which I parse the specific address "refId", which I then plug into a second GET request to the `Address` endpoint.  While this is logical its an extra GET request to the server, and I'm wondering if there is some way to describe a query in my backend so I can simply make a single GET request to a /person/{id}/address endpoint which finds the `Person` document with the specified id and returns the `Address` document from the "refId" in the `Person` (not the "address" part of the `Person` document, I want to return the actual `Address` document).

There isn't much I have already tried, as I don't have many ideas.  Since I'm using Spring WebFlux all of my server responses are in the form of Publishers (`Mono`/`Flux`) as that is what the repository returns, and I'm not sure how to work with those before returning them as a `ServerResponse` object.

Thank you.